# How to insert back a character in a string at the exact position where it was originally

Tags: r, purrr, stringr

I have strings that have dots here and there and I would like to remove them - that is done, and after some other operations - these are also done, I would like to insert the dots back at their original place - this is not done. How could I do that?

```
library(stringr)
stringOriginal <- c("abc.def","ab.cd.ef","a.b.c.d")
dotIndex <- str_locate_all(pattern ='\\.', stringOriginal)
stringModified <- str_remove_all(stringOriginal, "\\.")
```

I see that `str_sub()` may help, for example `str_sub(stringModified[2], 3,2) <- "."` gets me somewhere, but it is still far from the right place, and also I have no idea how to do it programmatically. Thank you for your time!

**update**

```
stringOriginal <- c("11.123.100","11.123.200","1.123.1001") 
stringOriginalF <- as.factor(stringOriginal) 
dotIndex <- str_locate_all(pattern ='\\.', stringOriginal) 
stringModified <- str_remove_all(stringOriginal, "\\.") 
stringNumFac <- sort(as.numeric(stringModified)) 
stringi::stri_sub(stringNumFac[1:2], 3, 2) <- "." 
stringi::stri_sub(stringNumFac[1:2], 7, 6) <- "." 
stringi::stri_sub(stringNumFac[3], 2, 1) <- "." 
stringi::stri_sub(stringNumFac[3], 6, 5) <- "." 
factor(stringOriginal, levels = stringNumFac)
```

after such manipulation, I am able to order the numbers and convert them back to strings and use them later for plotting.
But since I wouldn't know the position of the dot, I wanted to make it programmatical. Another approach for factor ordering is also welcomed. Although I am still curious about how to insert programmatically back a character in a string at the exact position where it was originally.

Comment: why not just reference the original variable? What's the purpose of inserting them back in the same place?

Comment: Because from probably the so many ways to order a factor variable I chose the most cumbersome one. I'll update the question with my factor ordering problem.

Comment: Are you really just trying to order by a certain order? In other words, do you use the `stringNumFac` later? You could do `stringOriginal[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\.','',stringOriginal)))]` to order stringOriginal by numeric order?

Comment: `as.factor(stringOriginal[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\.','',stringOriginal)))])` gives still the same order as `as.factor(stringOriginal)`. To answer your question, I use `stringOriginal ` as factor for plotting later. It looks better when these numbers with their respective dots (that should be preserved) are ordered in a human-readable way, since they are many :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be one of the cases for using base R's `strsplit`, which gives you a list, with a vector of substrings for each entry in your original vector. You can manipulate these with `lapply` or `sapply` very easily.

```r
split_string <- strsplit(stringOriginal, "[.]")
#> split_string
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "11"  "123" "100"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "11"  "123" "200"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "1"    "123"  "1001"
```

Now you can do this to get the numbers

```r
sapply(split_string, function(x) as.numeric(paste0(x, collapse = "")))
# [1] 11123100 11123200 11231001
```

And this to put the dots (or any replacement for the dots) back in:

```r
sapply(split_string, paste, collapse = ".")
# [1] "11.123.100" "11.123.200" "1.123.1001"
```

And you could get the location of the dots within each element of your original vector like this:

```r
lapply(split_string, function(x) cumsum(nchar(x) + 1))
# [[1]]
# [1]  3  7 11
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  3  7 11
#
# [[3]]
# [1]  2  6 11
```

Comment: I am missing something. ok, I am missing a lot, but I am trying to catch up. `lapply(split_string, function(x) cumsum(nchar(x) + 1))` how can I incorporate the result of it, the dots-index-position(ignoring the last index position) with the result of `sapply(split_string, function(x) as.numeric(paste0(x, collapse = "")))`. You already answered the question with this line `sapply(split_string, paste, collapse = ".")`, my problem, not that much, but this is on me and how I stated the problem.

Comment: And the more I think about it, the more I realize that if the dots are here and there, which might happen, getting dots' position won't mean they are reinserted correctly after I reorder the numerical strings let's say. with the df I work now - everything is fine, but..I should reconsider the approach. Anyhow, thank you very much for your time!